# .format() struggle. Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I'm facing some difficulties about .format().

```
 tup = [fname,lname,email,pwd,coun,add]

con = db.connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'lora');
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    insert_sql = ('INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(fname, lname, email, pwd, coun, add)  VALUES("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s" )'% (fname, lname, email,
                                                                                                              pwd, coun, add))
    cur.execute(insert_sql)
```

After the execution, it shows me this error.

```
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
    pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your 
    SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB 
    server version for the right syntax to use near \'add)  
    VALUES("","ee","","de","","")\' at line 1'
```

Comment: Step one:  Print out what `*tup` is.

Comment: Step two: never, ever use string interpolation to build up SQL queries.

Comment: tup = [fname,lname,email,pwd,coun,add]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is with `format()`.

I think the problem is that **`ADD`** is a MySQL Reserved Word

see the MySQL Reference Manual:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

---

To reference a reserved word as an identifier (such as a column name), the identifier will either need to be qualified with a table name or table alias, or (as in the case of the INSERT statement)

the identifier will need to be *escaped*

By default, MySQL uses backtick character to escape identifiers e.g.

```
 INSERT INTO ... ( ..., col, `add` ) VALUES 
                              ^  ^
```

(If `ANSI_QUOTES` is enabled in `sql_mode`, then we could use also double quotes to escape the identifier, as other databases like Oracle use.)

Preferred practice is to **avoid** using reserved words and keywords as identifiers.

---

The pattern shown in the code appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection. (We don't see that the variables incorporated into the SQL text are guaranteed to be  *safe*.

Best practice is to use *prepared statements* with *bind placeholders*.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Introduction

[Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)